# In ES6 class syntax why setPrototypeOf() work and other similar method don't

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-6

As I read MDN(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Sub_classing_with_extends) about inheriting property in class, they say that I need to use `Object.setPrototypeOf()`

```js
class Book {
  constructor(title) {
    this.name = "Book";
    this.title = title;
  }
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(Book.prototype, {
  state: 'OH',
  country: 'US'
})

let newBook = new Book('Lolita')
console.log(newBook.state) //OH
```

But when I check MDN about `Object.setPrototypeOf()`, they say it's slow and should use some other like `Object.create()`. But when I try it doesn't work

```js
class Book {
  constructor(title) {
    this.name = "Book";
    this.title = title;
  }
}

Book.prototype = Object.create({
  state: 'OH',
  country: 'US'
})

let newBook = new Book('Lolita')
console.log(newBook.state) //undefined
```

I think it's pretty strange since with normal prototype syntax `Object.create()` work well. And Book.prototype is object, so I don't see any reason why I can't add prototype like that.

**Note**: After I read the first answer by @Felix it's seem reasonable. But when I try to adjust the code a little bit I found other place where it should not work but turn out it work

```js
class Book {
  constructor(title) {
    this.name = "Book";
    this.title = title;
  }
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(Book.prototype, {
  state: 'OH',
  country: 'US'
})

class LibraryBook extends Book{}
LibraryBook.prototype = Object.create(Book.prototype)
let firstBook = new LibraryBook('Lolita')
console.log(firstBook.state)
```

Can you explain me about this case why it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `class` syntax, the `prototype` property of the resulting constructor function is **not writable and not configurable**. That means you cannot assign a new value to it, neither via an assignment expression nor via `Object.defineProperty`.

```js
class Book {}

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Book, 'prototype'));
```

---

> Can you explain me about this case why it work?

`LibraryBook.prototype = Object.create(Book.prototype)` has no effect. You can remove it and get the same result. `LibraryBook.prototype` is already an object that has `Book.prototype` as its prototype. That's what the `... extends Book` clause does.

```js
class Book {}
class LibraryBook extends Book {}

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(LibraryBook.prototype) === Book.prototype);
```

Comment: So `Object.setPrototype()` work because it rewrite the whole prototype while `Object.create()` doesn't because it only assign the new value for it, am I correct?

Comment: It works because it (internally) mutates the value of `Book.prototype`, it doesn't create (and assign) a new object. I.e. `var obj = {}; var oldObj = obj; Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, {}); console.log(obj === oldObj);` is `true` vs `var obj = {}; var oldObj = obj; obj = Object.create({}); console.log(obj === oldObj);` is `false`.

Comment: I have add one subclass and find that `Object.create()` work in this case for the subclass. Is this go against what you write above?

Comment: No. `LibraryBook.prototype = Object.create(Book.prototype)` has no effect. You can remove it and get the same result. `LibraryBook.prototype` is already an object that has `Book.prototype` as its prototype. That's what the `... extends Book` clause does. `class Book {}; class LibraryBook extends Book {}; console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(LibraryBook.prototype) === Book.prototype);` is `true`.

Comment: I have read in MDN that using `Object.setPrototypeOf()` effect the performance. Is there any way to avoid this problem. Setting the private or public variable in class is not standardized yet

Comment: *"Is there any way to avoid this problem."* Likely, but it depends on the actual problem you are trying to solve. In your example, the simplest solution would be to defined `state` and `country` inside the `Book` constructor. You could even do `Object.assign(this, someExistingObject)` to copy the properties from another object. It's unclear to me why you want to change/set the prototype.

Comment: Because when I learn JS inheritence they say that using it will help reduce the memory need for the object instance. Adding too much in constructor or using `Object.assign()` directly will likely increase the unnecessary data as they duplicate.

Comment: You can worry about memory when you actually have a problem. I wouldn’t worry about it now.